# unable to run my script that is not on the root folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, path

I'm unable to move my index.ts file inside a src folder to organize my project.

I'm using prisma and following the 'from the scratch tutorial' (https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch) which require just a `index.ts` to query the database. When I run the script just from the root folder `using npx ts-node index.ts` it runs fine.

But when I put it inside a folder (in my case, src/controller, two folders), it logs a

> error: Cannot find module './index.ts

If I run `npx ts-node src/controller/index.ts` with the path to index.ts, it does run fine, but there is a way to configure the path, so I can just type index.ts?

Comment: What's wrong with  current behavior?

Comment: Not practical, especially if I need to create more subfolders with diferent scripts. Also, I watched some videos and on none of them I see that command line (with the path on it). Do you now any way to how to automate it?